# Fast way to concatenate indicator variables in pair in r

Tags: r

I'd like to concatenate each pair of [,1], [,2] and [,3] for [1,] and [2,] separately. Please see the expected input and output below. What's the fastest way to do it when there are more than 3 variables? Thanks in advance!

Input:

```
data<-matrix(c(1,1,0,1,0,0),nrow=2,ncol=3)
data
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    1    1    0
```

Output:

```
 data
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    10    10    00
    [2,]    11    10    10
```

Explanation of the output

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    paste0([1,1],[1,2])    paste0([1,1],[1,3])    paste0([1,2],[1,3])
[2,]    paste0([2,1],[2,2])    paste0([2,1],[2,3])    paste0([2,2],[2,3])
```

Comment: Any automatic way? If I have more than 3 variables, that will be time-consuming

Comment: Thank for helping me! Please see the update of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `combn` to create combination of column numbers taken 2 at a time and use those indexes to subset and paste values.

```
combn(seq_len(ncol(data)), 2, function(x) paste0(data[, x[1]], data[, x[2]]))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "10" "10" "00"
#[2,] "11" "10" "10"
```